# reverse for view fails because argument is None

Tags: django, django-tables2

In tables.py, I have imported django-tables2

```
class CarownerTable(tables.Table):
    ...
    Car_registration=tables.LinkColumn('register_docs', args =[A('register__id')], text='View Register', orderable=False)
```

My urls.py looks like this,

```
url(r'^register_docs/$', views.register_docs, name='register_docs' ),
url(r'^register_docs/(?P<docid>(\d)+)$', views.register_docs, name='register_docs' ),
```

and the view as

```
def register_docs(request, docid=None):
    #This view allows for the display of the pdf file
    if docid is None:
        #this line here loads a default image
        doclink = '........./Car/Misc/noImageOnFile.pdf'
        return HttpResponse(doclink, content_type="application/pdf")
    else:
        register_doc_path = Register.objects.get(pk=docid).register_File_Path

        register_doc_data = open(register_doc_path, "rb").read()
        t = loader.get_template('carmanager/display_docs.html')
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'file':register_doc_data})
        output = t.render(variables)
        return HttpResponse(register_doc_data, content_type="application/pdf")
```

The issue is that when I load results some of the objects don't have a document attached to it. causing this

```
Reverse for 'register_docs' with arguments '(None,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['carmanager/register_docs/(?P<docid>(\\d)+)$', 'carmanager/register_docs$']
```

I tried and create two url one that accepts an argument and one that doesn't but it still wont allow the table to load with those who doesn't have. I want both to load even though a car registration document cant loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to not use a linkColumn if some of your records are missing values for the agrs.

If you need to display information in django-tables2  where a column might or might not have infomation needed for a url link use

```
templateColumn
```

for example

```
templateRegister = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name="carmanager/registertemplate.html")
```

registertemplate.html should look like this

```
<a  {% if record.register__id %} target="_Blank" href="/carmanager/register_docs/{{record.register__id}}"> View Register {%else%} > No register {%endif%}</a>
```